# Add the duplicate in another list

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I want to place the duplicates from one list in another list. In the follow example, I am attempting to create a list `red_dup` that contains every item that contains a 'red' id that is duplicated. Similarly, I want to do the same for each food in a `food_dup` list.

What I have:

```
values = [[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red2', 'food4'], [1, 'red1', 'food9']]
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
red_dup = [[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red1', 'food9']]
food_dup = [[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red2', 'food4']]
```

In my code the "values" comes from a generator function from a class.

The function returns these [values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I68X1.png).

The 1 is the distance, and the red or blue is the entity distance from the food.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovYsZ.png) is what code returns. The red underline is a X, Y coordinates.

Comment: I have only untreated variable "values" that comes from a generator function.

Comment: I will edit the post showing the code.

Comment: Done, i edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dict to store and filter for dupe values

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for item in values:
    _, color, food = item 
    res[color].append(item)
    res[food].append(item)
    

[v for v in res.values() if len(v) > 1]
```

result:

```
[[[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red1', 'food9']],
 [[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red2', 'food4']]]
```

Comment: That works thanks, can you explain 

`[v for v in res.values() if len(v) > 1]` 

I'm beginner and don't know this type of "for" loop

Comment: @Guildc12 This is called a 'list comprehension'. It simply says "For each element in the list `res.values()`, put it in the final list if it has a length greater than one - meaning it has been duplicated."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
values = [[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red2', 'food4'], [1, 'red1', 'food9']]

red_dup = []
food_dup = []

for i in values:
    red=[k for k in values if k[1]==i[1]]
    if len(red)>1:
        red_dup.extend(red)
    food = [k for k in values if k[2]==i[2]]
    if len(food)>1:
        food_dup.extend(food)

red_dup=sorted(red_dup, key=lambda x: [x[1], x[2]])[::2]
food_dup=sorted(food_dup, key=lambda x: [x[2], x[1]])[::2]

>>>print(red_dup)
#[[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red1', 'food9']]
>>>print(food_dup)
#[[1, 'red1', 'food4'], [1, 'red2', 'food4']]
```

Comment: I used DefaultDicts and that worked, however, thanks.